# How can I select particular href tag using attributes

Tags: html, css

I want to create the selector using a tag href attributes. I try the below one but not working well. Please check the below code

**HTML**
`<a href="https://google.com/">Google</a> <a href="https://codepen.io/pen/">Codepen</a>`

**CSS**
`ahref="https://google.com/" {   background-color: #f00;   color: #fff;   padding: 10px; }`

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors to learn about CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this. Also Here I attached the codepen. Plesae try this

```
a[href="https://google.com/"] {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ashok-kannan-dev/pen/mdpWLvG

Comment:  You can create a snippet directly in SO with the `<>` button, no need for CodePen for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use class it's help you to reuse a code.

html

```
   <a href="https://google.com/" class="selected">Google</a>
   <a href="https://codepen.io/pen/">Codepen</a>
   <a href="https://gmail.com" class="selected">Gmail</a>
```

css

```
.selected {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

here is sample work https://codepen.io/imnoorfahad/pen/yLppaLa